# Interpolation of missing values in Julia

Tags: julia, interpolation, libraries

Suppose I have an array where some values are NaN. For example `[1, 2, NaN, 4]`.
Is there any Julia library that able to fill the array with interpolated values?
So that the result would be `[1, 2, 3, 4]`.

I can not see if I am able to do it with Interpolations.jl.
For now, I am not concerned with the interpolation function. I just need to fill this linearly.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

You can just do it yourself, as long as it is not an edge case, find the next and previous value and take the average.

Comment: Thank you, that is the plan. I just want to know if there is something already done through library that would be better or efficient.

Comment: if your missing data were `missing` not `NaN` you can use https://github.com/invenia/Impute.jl.

Comment: Thank you Bogumił, I would look into that.